# SQL Query nvarchar to date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, hana, nvarchar

I am working on SAP HANA Studio and have tried to run SQL command that converts an entire column of field, nvarchar, into one of field, date.

My dates have format: `dd-mon-yyyy (i.e '29-Mar-1997') with field nvarchar(11)`.

I have looked at previous questions and SQL command documentation (for `functions like CAST, CONVERT, TO_DATE, STR_TO_DATE`) and have not gotten a solution.

Typical errors I get are: Function not recognized, or, `Error while parsing Service Date as DATE at function to_date()`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks 
-Diana

Comment: What do you get when you run SELECT STR_TO_DATE('29-Mar-1997', '%d-%b-%Y'); ?

Comment: @Gerfried Hey, when I execute 'SELECT STR_TO_DATE(\"Service Date\", \"%d-%b-%Y\")' + 'FROM \"ListCurrentICC\"', where \"Service Date\" is my column name I get: InternalError: dberror(Connection.prepareStatement): 328 - invalid name of function or procedure: STR_TO_DATE: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)

Comment: @Gerfried when i execute, 'SELECT STR_TO_DATE(\"29-Mar-1997\", \"%d-%b-%Y\")', I get InternalError: dberror(Connection.prepareStatement): 328 - invalid name of function or procedure: STR_TO_DATE: line 1 col 8 (at pos 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`TO_DATE()`](http://sap.optimieren.de/hana/hana/html/sql_function_to_date.html):

```
select to_date(col, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff, this worked. Thank you! I was accidentally enclosing the 'DD-MON-YYYY' in '" ", rather than in ' '. Apparently the " " indicates it is a column name and ' ' is just for a format string. Dont know if that make sense.

Comment: @Diana . . . Always use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your database driver/layer in SAP HANA does not support all mySQL functions. 
Please connect to your database directly (using command-line or a gui like HeidiSQL) and create a view in your database:

```
CREATE VIEW view_tablename AS
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`Service Date`, '%d-%b-%Y') AS ServiceDateDt, * FROM tablename
```

Then use view_tablename instead of tablename in all your queries - because view_tablename has the additional date field "ServiceDateDt".

Comment: I tried doing this on the SQL sap hana terminal. As you said, it did not recognize that function. I ended up using the to_date() function as suggested above. I will for sure create a view so thank you for that.

Comment: Yup! I have my view created as: CREATE VIEW view_ListCurrentICC AS
SELECT to_date("Service Date", '%d-%b-%Y') AS ServiceDateDt, * FROM "USER1"."ListCurrentICC"